# How can I show a list in a dropdown menu?

Tags: python, kivy

I want to select an item from a list. This list could be ex: `SKU 1, SKU 2, Item 3`, and is in a csv file in my case, but it's not relevant.

My problem is that when I activate the dropdown menu it shows the list as many times as the number of component and every component is the list itself.

So my result is:

> SKU 1, SKU 2, Item 3
> SKU 1, SKU 2, Item 3
> SKU 1, SKU 2, Item 3

instead of

> SKU 1
> SKU 2
> Item 3

Here is my code:

```
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
import csv


dropdown = DropDown()
with open("List.csv") as f:
    with open('List.csv', newline='') as csv_file:   
        reader = list(csv.reader(csv_file))
        for row in reader:
            a = row

            for i in range(len(a)):


                btn = Button(text='%s' % a, size_hint_y=None, height=44)


                btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: set_item(btn.text))


                dropdown.add_widget(btn)

mainbutton = Button(text='List', size_hint=(None, None),width=600)

def set_item(btn):
    dropdown.select(btn)
    # string = '%s' % (btn)
    # print(string)
    

mainbutton.bind(on_release=dropdown.open)

dropdown.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(mainbutton, 'text', x))

runTouchApp(mainbutton)
```

where List.csv is the name of my file.

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1):

You are putting the entire `row` in the text of each `Button` with the code:

```
btn = Button(text='%s' % a, size_hint_y=None, height=44)
```

because `a` is the entire row. Try changing that line to:

```
btn = Button(text='%s' % a[i], size_hint_y=None, height=44)
```

which uses the `i` variable to select the desired element of `row`.

Also,  I don't understand why you are opening the `List.csv` file twice. I believe you can eliminate the line:

```
with open("List.csv") as f:
```

Comment: Thank you! it works perfectly, also that line was an error. Thank you a lot!